# O que significa "abrir sozinho ou grei"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro

O poema "Intimação" de Carlos Drummond de Andrade tem esta estrofe:

> Abre em nome da lei.
>   Abre sem nome e lei.
>   Abre mesmo sem rei.
>   Abre, sozinho ou grei.
>   Não, não abras; à força
>   de intimar-te, repara:
>   eu já te desventrei.

Segundo meu dicionário, "grei" é "nação, povo, grupo". O que é "abrir, sozinho ou grei", então? Me parece estranho porque "sozinho" é um adjetivo enquanto "grei" é um substantivo.

Tenho dificuldade também com a sintaxe em "à força de intimar-te"; quer dizer algo como "Já te intimei tantas vezes que ..." ?

Temos aqui o [poema completo declamado pelo próprio.](http://palavrarecitada.blogspot.pt/2013/08/carlos-drummond-de-andrade-intimacao.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A interpretação mais inteligível para mim é:

> Abre, tu (que estás) sozinho; ou tu, povo.

Ou seja, neste verso o intimador nomeia o destinatário da intimação: abre, sejas tu um indivíduo ou um grupo.

Consultei vários dicionários, e mesmo o Houaiss e o da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa definem ***grei*** apenas como substantivo, com os significados que encontramos nos dicionários online como o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/grei) ou o [Micahelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=grei), nomeadamente (dicionário da Academia):

> *s. f.* (do latim *grex, gregis* ‘rebanho’). **1.** Rebanho de gado miúdo. **2.** Conjunto de fieis de uma paróquia ou diocese. **3.** Conjunto dos membros de um partido ou sócios de um grémio ou associação. **4.** Conjunto dos cidadãos de uma mesma nação ou país. **5.** *Desusado* Conjunto dos súbditos do rei, o seu povo.

Portanto não vejo como interpretar *grei* a não ser como substantivo com o significado de conjunto de pessoas. A questão reduz-se então a interpretar *sozinho* como *indivíduo*. A frase *abre, tu sozinho ou grei* é gramatical: abre, sejas tu uma pessoa só ou uma grei. Sem o *tu* fica de gramaticalidade duvidosa, mas tratando-se de um poema, temos que aceitar a liberdade poética. Creio que há aqui também uma alusão às expressões *sem lei nem rei* e *sem lei nem grei*, (*sem lei* e *sem rei* aparecem nos versos anteriores) que significam (Houaiss) *sem rumo, por conta do acaso, ao sabor dos ventos*, e que neste caso dão uma ideia de arbitrariedade.

[*À força de*](http://www.aulete.com.br/for%C3%A7a) significa *à custa de, por meio de*, mas eu concordo que aqui transmite também uma ideia de insistência.

Answer (score -3):

Isso é uma simples licença poética. Não há porque ficar buscando explicações lógicas.